# Как сделать, что бы страница листалась целиком слайдами и при смене слайда новый слайд накладывался на старый отбрасывая на него тень?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Как сделать, что бы страница листалась целиком слайдами и при смене слайда новый слайд накладывался на старый отбрасывая на него тень?

Вот видео как должны выглядеть в итоге анимация слайдов при переходе  https://youtu.be/qbpiDaykgII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не  понятно что конкретно вы имеете ввиду, пишите более конкретные и развернутые вопросы. Если я правильно понял, то для вашего варианта вот тут куча пример – http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

Comment: Добавил видео поясняющее анимацию переходов слайдов.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, сегодня поковырял этот пример и частично сделал то, что мне надо.